# Запятые и точки в дробных числах в си при вводе чисел

Tags: c, локаль

Интересно почему сразу заканчивается выполнение программы при попытке ввода дробных чисел с  точкой, а не с запятой, хотя в самом коде используются точки? Не оставляю кода потому что считаю это бессмысленно? Кто-то может мне разъяснить этот вопрос?

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести, давайте код.

Comment: @steelhouse, насколько понимаю, Вы начали изучать программирование на Си.

Советую делать это в Linux и на первых порах не использовать русские буквы.

Comment: Он при этом ругается? как? скорее всего перед затрытием он пишет в консоль ошибку, но Вы ее не видите, так как консоль сразу закрывается. Попробуйте запустить через командную строку.

Comment: Просто для изучения программирования в Linux, нужно знать Linux, у меня пока времени на изучения OS нету.

Comment: >Просто для изучения программирования в Linux, нужно знать Linux

Совершенно не обязательно. Просто программирование в Linux вынуждает быть внимательней к мелочам и стандартам.

Comment: Ну если обычный дистрибутив Ubuntu подойдёт, я могу попробовать. Просто мне кажется, что там больше работы в терминале надо будет выполнять.

Comment: Убунта вполне годится, мой рабочая машина как раз под ней. А полноценных IDE тут чуть ли не больше, чем под Windows :) И в консоль лазить не надо, всё будет интегрировано.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

На самом деле многие библиотечные функции используют текущую [локаль](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C). В частности, от текущей локали зависит, какой разделитель целой и дробной части ожидают увидеть функции. При запуске программа наследует системную локаль, похоже в вашем случае это русская локаль. В качестве демонстрации приведу программу:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void test(const char* str) {
  printf("%s => ", str); 
  char* endptr;
  double num = strtod(str, &endptr);
  // Checking if whole string parsed
  if (endptr != str + strlen(str)) {
    printf("ERROR");
  } else {
    printf("%lf", num);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void locale_info() {
  printf("Current locale: %s\n", setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, NULL));
  printf("Current delimiter: '%s'\n", localeconv()->decimal_point);
}

int main() {
  const char* dot = "10.5";
  const char* comma = "10,5";
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
  locale_info();
  test(dot);
  test(comma);
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.utf8");
  locale_info();
  test(dot);
  test(comma);
}
```

У меня программа выводит:

```
Current locale: en_US.utf8
Current delimiter: '.'
10.5 => 10.500000
10,5 => ERROR
Current locale: ru_RU.utf8
Current delimiter: ','
10.5 => ERROR
10,5 => 10,500000
```

Видно, что в зависимости от локали, программа по разному интерпретирует одни и те же данные. Чтобы избежать таких неожиданностей, можно при запуске программы устанавливать стандартную локаль для числовых данных:

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");
```

Comment: отличный ответ, почему только 2 плюса?

Comment: Некогда читать все.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Очень доходчиво написано.

Comment: программы стартуют в C локале, поэтому не нужно вызывать `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");` если других `setlocale` в программе нет. В общем случае (не к этому вопросу) [`setlocale` может не иметь эффекта на с++ функции](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235302.aspx).